# "To know + object + to + infinitive" works here, right?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I made up a sentence: "Whom do you know in the picture who has been in jail?"

Is the sentence correct? If so, can it be rephrased as "Whom do you know in the picture to have been in jail?"?

Comment: "Accusative and infinitive" constructions (which were actually adopted from Latin) are very much part of written English, and not part of most people's spoken English.

Comment: Sentences are ambiguous and could mean who are you acquainted with or who do you know as a fact went to jail.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] Whom [do you know] [in the picture] who has been in jail?

> [2] Whom do you know [in the picture] to have been in jail?

We use the condensed form for clarity. #1 without the bracketed words should be

> **Who** ... has been in jail?

The mistakes hence are the use of *whom* and the extra *who*.

We build up the sentence further:

> **Who** do you know ... has been in jail?

> **Who** do you know ... **is** to have been in jail?

Somehow, I feel that *know* works less well than *think* or *believe*:

> **Who** do you think (or believe) ... **is** to have been in jail?

#2 without the bracketed words is shown above.

Its mistakes hence are the use of *whom* and the missing **is**.

We use the subject form **who** in **who has been** and **who is**, not the object form.

Answer (score -1):

I think grammatically both your sentences are correct, although the first one does sound unlike what a native speaker would say.

I find the rephrased sentence better.

Answer (score -1):

You can rephrase the sentence by saying: "to have been" and it would sound stuffy.

Both are correct, though I feel like it should either be said:

> Who do you know in the picture that's been in jain?

Or

> Do you know *anyone/someone* in the picture that's been in jain? (*use the pronouns with
> little difference in meaning)*;

Don't forget "whom" is formal and is not preferable in every-day speech.